# Unable to locate package winehq-stable?

Tags: package-management, wine

I ran these commands.

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key
sudo apt-key add Release.key
sudo apt-add-repository https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

The last command gives the error:
Unable to locate package winehq-stable

Comment: What release of Ubuntu are you running?   Is it supported by the PPA?  I looked at what it supports, but not knowing what you are running means we can't help yet.  (though it could also be the winehq-stable as I didn't see a package of that name in the random release I looked at.

Comment: It's Ubuntu 18.10.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as it turns out wine 4.0 is released.
I followed the instruction from https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/01/wine-4-0 and was able to install wine.